# Only show if there are sibling entries

Tags: categories

I am showing entries from the same category on a single entry page.

```
<aside>
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <ul>

    {exp:channel:entries
      channel="articles"
      disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
      require_entry="yes"
      dynamic="off"
      related_categories_mode="on"
    }

    <li><a href="/articles/detail/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>

    {/exp:channel:entries}

        </ul>
    </aside>
```

All good but I only want the  container to show if there are those entries. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the wrapping html into the channel entries loop, like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="articles"
  disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
  require_entry="yes"
  dynamic="off"
  related_categories_mode="on"
}

{if count == 1}
  <aside>
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <ul>
{/if}

<li><a href="/articles/detail/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>

{if count == total_results}
    </ul>
  </aside>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If there are no results, nothing will get displayed. If you want to trigger something to happen, just use the no_results trigger:

```
{if no_results}{embed="inc/random_entries"}{/if}
```

Iain

Comment: I was so close! Thanks Iain, that works great.

Comment: All good. Could you mark as answered if it has solved your question please :)

Comment: Oops apologies, done!